# Is this function locally integrable ? Needs spherical coordinates!

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $ d\in \mathbb{N}$ be the dimension we consider. Let $\mu$ be a probability density on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Consider vector fields of the form $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$

$$ f(x):=\frac{x}{\|x\|^k},~~~~k\leq d.$$

Define the convolution of $f$ and $\mu$ as

$$ f*\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)\mu(y)dy. $$

Now is it possible to show $f*\mu\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R
}^d)$ ?  Its funny because I can show $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ [Integrability / integrals of functions of the form $1/|x|$. Singularities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4149465/integrability-integrals-of-functions-of-the-form-1-x-singularities)  , but the non-local behaviour of the convolution "forces me to consider $f$ on non-compact sets".

---

Attempt : let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be compact. Let $f_i*\mu$ be the i-th component of $f*\mu$.
$$ \|f_i*\mu\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\leq \int_{\Omega}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\Big|\frac{(x_i-y_i)}{\|x-y\|^k}\Big|\mu(y)dydx, $$

Now I want to make the substitution $y_j=x_j+\text{spherical coordinates}$ : https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelkoordinaten#Verallgemeinerung_auf_n-dimensionale_Kugelkoordinaten  But since the $x$ coordinate can only be taken in the compact set $\Omega$ I'm stuck...

Comment: I think its actually in $L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ by Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality

Comment: @CalvinKhor thanks! :) Thats surprising, could you elaborate a bit or do you have a good reference ? I found this but it is a bit vague http://math.mit.edu/~lguth/PolyMethod/lect30.pdf

Comment: Actually I take it back, I think it may not hold for the $p=1$ endpoint. (The ‘standard’ reference is Stein’s singular integrals and differentiability properties but it’s not an easy read either. I’m on mobile and it’s not easy for me to check the assumptions now)

Comment: yeah I was just doing some searching and this inequality has problems at $p=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can just prove this directly. Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be compact. Then for each $i=1,\dots,d$\begin{align*}
\int_K \vert f_i \ast \mu \vert dx & \leqslant \int_K \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{\vert x_i -y_i \vert}{\vert x-y \vert^k} \mu(y) dydx \\
&=  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \int_K\frac{\vert x_i -y_i \vert}{\vert x-y \vert^k} \mu(y) dxdy \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mu(y) \int_K \frac{\vert x_i-y_i \vert}{\vert x-y \vert^k} d x dy
\end{align*} where I used Tonelli's Theorem to swap the integrals. Next, given some $y \in \mathbb{R}$, choose $R>0$ such that $\vert K \vert = \vert B_R(y) \vert = \vert B_1 \vert R^d$ (by $\vert A \vert $ I mean the Lebesgue measure of $A$). Note carefully that $R$ doesn't actually depend on $y$ since one could choose $R$ such that $\vert K \vert = \vert B_R(0) \vert =  \vert B_R(y) \vert $ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then  \begin{align*} 
\int_K \frac{\vert x_i-y_i \vert}{\vert x-y \vert^k} d x & \leqslant \int_{B_R(y)} \frac{\vert x_i-y_i \vert}{\vert x-y \vert^k} d x \\
& \leqslant \int_{B_R(y)} \vert x-y \vert^{1-k} d x \\
&= \int_0^R \int_{\partial B_r(y)} \vert x-y \vert^{1-k} d S dr\\
&= \frac{d\vert B_1 \vert}{d-k+1}  R^{n-k+1} \\
&= \frac{d\vert B_1 \vert^{1-\frac 1 d}}{d-k+1}  \vert K \vert^{\frac{n-k+1}{d}} =: C_0
\end{align*} via polar coordinates. The first inequality holds since the integrand is monotone decreasing as we move radially out from $y$. Thus, \begin{align*}
\int_K \vert f_i \ast \mu \vert dx & \leqslant C_0  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mu(y) d y = C_0< \infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: What is $\tilde{K}$?

Comment: Doesnt the constant $C$ in the integral $I_2$ depend on $y$?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't think my proof as it stood was correct. I've corrected my answer - hopefully it is now correct :) Sorry about the confusion

Comment: In your first inequality ( and those that follow ) did you mean to write $B_R(y)$?

Comment: also whats $n$?

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, by $n$ I meant $d$ - force of habit.

Comment: Cheers for you answer (there is one more added detail that $k\leq d+1$ for one of those integrals to be finite) :) silly follow up question : if instead $f:\mathbb{R}^{2d}\to\mathbb{R}^{2d}$, $f_k(x,v)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \frac{x}{\|x\|^k} \end{pmatrix}$, would $f_k\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{2d}) $ for $k\leq d$ or $k\leq 2d$? Like does adding arbitrary extra dimensions increase the the power to which I can put the singularity.